# Unable to use password_verify($password, $hash)

Tags: php, password-hash

So I have a Registration page and a Login page, the registration page works perfectly fine but the Login page doesnt seem to work and I cant seem to figure it out.

My database seems to be working as I am able to echo out the hashed password onto the page of the login, it seems to have something to do with 
password_verify()

Registration Page (Working)

```
<?php 
include("assets/includes/conn.php");

$user = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$cPass = $_POST['c-pass'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$options = [
    'cost' => 11
];

if($pass == $cPass){

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, pass, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $user, $h_p, $email);

    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $h_p = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $options)."\n";
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $stmt->execute();

    echo "Created";
    echo $h_p;
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();

}
```

Login Page (Not working)

```
<?php 
include("assets/includes/conn.php");

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows == 1){
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $hash = $row['pass'];

    if(password_verify($password, $hash)){
        echo "Yes";
    } else {
        echo "No<br/>";
        echo "" . $hash . "<br/>";
        echo $password;

    }
}
```

Comment: I have a few thoughts as to why it's failing, but you can see the answer below.

Comment: Make sure you are [displaying errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) in case you have a problem with variables not being properly sent to the script, etc.

Comment: @Mike The issue is I dont think it is an error, it is simply telling me that the password isnt correct even though it is, which might have something to do with it being hashed

Comment: @TristanSchlarman Don't assume anything. Maybe you're not correctly passing the values to the script.

Comment: Is there a unique index on `username` in your DB?

Comment: @Mike I even checked the hash when it was first created before it was put in the db and then compared it to the one that I got from `$hash = $row['pass']` and they are the same thing, and I made sure that my password was the same one that I registered with, I even made more than 1 account to make sure yet they all claim that the password is incorrect.

Comment: What is the column type of the password in your DB?

Comment: @Mike [link](http://imgur.com/a/gXGX1) That is what the table looks like might answer that

Comment: In both cases, do `var_dump($_POST);` to make sure the values are what you think they are. Also check for white space before and after the values.

Comment: @Mike Just checked, made a new account and saved the data and then logged in and compared them, same thing. Still not letting me in

Comment: Just checked *what* exactly? Did you do `var_dump`?

Comment: @Mike, yes sorry. I added `var_dump($_POST)` on both the registration and login pages

Comment: @TristanSchlarman No idea then. I don't see anything in the code itself that looks wrong.

Comment: What's the size of your password column? maybe it's too short and it's being truncated. from the php.net site, *Therefore, it is recommended to store the result in a database column that can expand beyond 60 characters (255 characters would be a good choice).*

Comment: @Augwa  It is set to Varchar(255)

Comment: *Welcome to Stack* @TristanSchlarman *cheers*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is that the `\n` in:

```
$h_p = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $options)."\n";
                                                         ^^
```

is (*invisibly*) adding a [carriage return/linefeed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) at the end of your password/hash.

You can either remove it.

```
$h_p = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $options);
```

or [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) it:

```
$h_p = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $options)."\n";
$h_p = trim($h_p);
```

I honestly don't know why the manual on [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) doesn't make a mention about it and the usage of it for storing it in a database (or a file).

**NOTE:** What the docs **haven't used** here, was to **assign** a **variable** to the example, which is what was done in the question here. Some may think that using the example and assigning a variable to it will work; *it won't*; not for storing the hash and then verifying it after.

The example from the manual reads as:

```
echo password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";
```

But doing:

```
$var = password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";
```

will in fact (*theoretically*) contain a 61-length string (because of the concated linefeed character), instead of the intended 60 without the linefeed character.

- So now you need to clear out your present hashes and start over with a new set of hashes.

Have a look at [this sandbox code example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5931c322be5965de5eab326164da8d2d2f15c5a1)

When run, it will output something like this:

```
$2y$10$494GPYzaynEkfYxE3wcAj.OtwBU3CCwTMXOHKbdJmOqwMXRmq6v1u
61
```

Just in case the URL's a 404 later on, here's the code for the above:

```
<?php
$foo = password_hash('mypass',  PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";
echo $foo;
echo strlen($foo);
```

On an added note; you should also use a prepared statement for your `SELECT` just as you did for the `INSERT`; it's much safer.

Comment: @TristanSchlarman You're welcome. I was in the question last night but had to go to bed. I then revisited the question today to add my answer. It can now be marked as solved.

Comment: @TristanSchlarman just give that gray tick under the up/down arrows a click till it turns green; that's how the question is marked as solved/closed.

Comment: Interesting point there, I've done that before and never figured out why it messed up

Comment: @Darren I take it that the code you were using has now been changed; or did you end up using something else since that didn't contain the `\n`?